# how can i add html output (Ex : a YES and NO button) to the output of an intent in watson

Tags: watson-conversation

I have already created a dialog flow and the same works well in android.However i am looking to integrate the below:-

1.Adding HTML response from Intents
2.How to write the click events for those HTML objects in android
3.ability to call 3rd party services from watson assistant(i.e a particular input from user /a button click would call a 3rd party service and perhaps 4.return the result back to watson objects which can be displayed in the mobile.screen

I am stuck at the very 1st point.Kindly suggest.

Comment: One question per post and you should give an example of what you have done so far.

Answer (score 0):

Create a dialog node and put your HTML code in the dialog response for the intent. It is then up to your application or front end to render it.